# Sorting IP addresses in vim

Tags: sorting, vim, ip-address

I have just discovered the command `:sort n` in vim (how did I not know about that?!), which has *almost* done exactly what I need.

What I am trying to sort, though, is a long list of IP addresses (it's an "allow hosts" file to be `Include`d into our apache config), and it would be nice for `:sort n` to be able to recognise that `123.45.6.7` should sort before `123.45.16.7` (for example).

Is it a safe assumption that I should be less OCD about it and not worry, because I'm not going to be able to do this without a mildly-complex `sed` or `awk` command or something?

To be clear, the rows all look something like:

```
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Allow from 5.6.7.8
Allow from 9.10.11.12
```

etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vim sort seems to be stable in practice (but it is not guaranteed). Therefore you can try:

```
:%sort n /.*\./
:%sort n /\.\d\+\./
:%sort n /\./
:%sort n
```

Which will sort by number after the last dot (`*` is greedy), then by number after the first dot following a dot and digits, then by number after the first dot, and last by the first number.

Comment: Almost entirely perfect (and the only reason it wasn't it because I'd not mentioned that some of my rows were netmasks). Thank you; that got me far enough to sort the netmasks out myself.

Comment: Using pipe you can execute it all in one go: `:%sort n /.*\./ | %sort n /\.\d\+\./ | %sort n /\./ | %sort n`

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward way to achieve the correct sorting order without
relying on the stability of the sorting algorithm implemented by the
`:sort` command, is to prepend zeroes to the numbers within the IP
addresses, so that all of the components in them consist of exactly
three digits.

1. Prepend zeros to the single-digit and two-digit numbers:

   ```
   :%s/\<\d\d\?\>/0&/g|%&&
   ```
2. Sort the lines comparing IP addresses as text:

   ```
   :sort r/\(\d\{3}\)\%(\.\d\{3}\)\{3}/
   ```
3. Strip redundant leading zeros:

   ```
   :%s/\<00\?\ze\d//g
   ```

To run all three steps as a single command, one can use the following
one-liner:

```
:%s/\<\d\d\?\>/0&/g|%&&|sor r/\(\d\{3}\)\%(\.\d\{3}\)\{3}/|%s/\<00\?\ze\d//g
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a vim user so I can't offer a direct way to do it with builtin commands, however it's possible to replace a section of text with the output of it run through a command. So, a simple script like this could be used:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

input_lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
sorted_lines = sorted(input_lines,
                      key=lambda line: map(int, line.split()[-1].split('.')))
for line in sorted_lines:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

See https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442419-vim-tips-working-with-external-commands, section "Filtering text through external filters", which explains how you can use this as a filter within vim.

This script should do what you want and will work on any region where all the selected lines end in an IPv4 address.

Comment: Goodness, thank you. I was trying to avoid running through a script (mainly because it's a not-live-yet Production server, so has a bare-bones install and `python` is not on there), but that looks amazing; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
:%!sort -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n
```

`-t .` means use `.` as delimiter.
Then sort numerically from 4th column to 1st column.